# how to remove background from a div contained in another div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="white">
 <div class="transparent">
   ----
 </div>
 <div class="content">
   ----
 </div>
</div>
```

I have a parent div `.white` which have white background color. This parent div have many children div's. Now I want  to make the background color of `.transparent` div transparent.
So please help me.

And also, I cannot take transparent div outside the parent `.white` div.

Comment: giving background transparent doesnt work?  or you want something else?

Comment: Elements are `transparent` by default. If you want to be able to see through the parent then that's not possible.

Comment: is .white inside other div

Comment: There is a Firefox only solution; make `background-image` of `.transparent::before` to the element behind using `-moz-element()`, adjust the element to correct position, and remember to add `overflow: hidden` on the `.transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The children are inside the parent. The only way to exclude the background in that area is by making a background-image in which the area hasn't got a color.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<div class="black">
<div class="white"> <!--parent-->
<div class="black">
 ----
</div>
<div class="content">
 ----
</div>
</div> <!--parent-->
</div>
```

**EDIT**

well it will work if every thing is fixed or use javascript:

Html

```
<div class='bg'>
<div class='white'>

<div class='transparent'>
<div id='peek' class='bg'></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg {
background: url('a.jpg');
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
}
.white {
background: #fff;
padding: 40px;   <= this is parameter
}
.transparent {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
#peek {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -40px;   <= this is result
left: -40px;  <= this is result
}
```

i hope you understood

Comment: This idea seems to be useful. But still I need some more. Because even the parent div have a one more parent which has a background image. So I used that same background again in the child div. But it is still not seamless. Anybody can find the difference between GrandParent div and child div.

Comment: Thanks yr. I got your point. you are forcing transparent div to come outside. That's good. But it may conflict in the case of responsive screens. Although I did it by using the same background image as in the grandparent div, and making its attachment fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unless you use a background image like @LinkinTED said..
But if the background color of `.white` is not color less you can use this css property for that `.transparent` div

```
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

to make the `.transparent` background transparent

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `background:transparent;` and it should work.

Here's a working fiddle, with parent div blue so that you can see that the transparent one is actually transparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/rg0jpw74/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be working for me.